# Adding rayhandler in LibGDx causes issues in InputListener

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, box2dlights

I am trying out Libgdx, and I have an actor which performs some action whenever we click on it. So far it is working fine. Now I want to add light to the actor. After doing some research I came across Box2DLights. When I tried adding it to my project onClick  Actor which was working fine does not seem to work. I am pretty sure this is due to rayhandler/Box2DLights because that is the only change I am making. here is the minimal change that I made to include  Box2DLights.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    private RayHandler rayHandler;
    private World world;

    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
        rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
        rayHandler.setAmbientLight(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1f);
        rayHandler.setBlurNum(3);
    }

     @Override
    public void show() {
        viewport = new FitViewport(1080, 720);
        stage = new Stage(viewport);
        rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(stage.getCamera().combined);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        //some custom rendering logic, but nothing related to rayHandler, excluding this for brevity.
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
        rayHandler.updateAndRender();
    }
```

Now When I debugged, I realised the the onClick is

### working little below the actual actor

, that means somehow the coordinates sifted(I know weird).
Can you please help?

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand what you meant by `projecting the coordinates`. The above code is pretty much everything I am doing related to coordinates. Should we use a different camera for this?

Comment: box2lights doesn't auto-acquire custom viewports, and restores the 'default one' after the updateAndRender called - your need to set your custom 'fitted' viewport to rayHandler so that it would restore it correctly- using the `rayHandler.useCustomViewport(...)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Mikhail Churbanov for your response [here](https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights/issues/110).
If somebody else stumbles on this again here is the solution which worked.

```
viewport = new FitViewport(1080, 720);
rayHandler.useCustomViewport(viewport.getScreenX(),
                             viewport.getScreenY(),
                             viewport.getScreenWidth(),
                             viewport.getScreenHeight());
```

The explaination is `box2lights doesn't auto-acquire custom viewports, and restores the 'default one' after the updateAndRender called - your need to set your custom 'fitted' viewport to rayHandler so that it would restore it correctly- using the rayHandler.useCustomViewport(...) method.`
All credits to @mikahi churbanov